# How to assign a CSS class to the Stock Quantity in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, css, woocommerce

I'm trying to display Stock Quantity text in the following format.

"How Many In Stock?" "20"

You can check it live on the following link:

https://spendr.dk/shop/

I'm using the following code.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','bbloomer_show_stock_shop', 10);

function bbloomer_show_stock_shop() {
global $product;
if ( $product->stock ) { // if manage stock is enabled 
if ( number_format( $product->stock,0,'','' ) < 3 ) { // if stock is low
echo '<div class="remaining">Only ' . number_format($product->stock,0,'','') . ' left in stock!</div>';
} 

else {
echo '<div class="remaining">' . 'How many in stock?</div>' . 
number_format($product->stock,0,'','');
}
}
}
```

Now I want to adjust the "Stock Quantity" (Example: 20). I'm trying to add a CSS Class to the stock quantity. I want to show it, right next to the "How Many In Stock?" text.

How can I add a CSS class to the Stock Quantity? in PHP.

Thank You.

Comment: '<span class="class_name">' .  number_format($product->stock,0,'','') . '</span>'

Answer (score 0):

First, modify your style for remaining class

i.e `.remaining { display: inline-block; }`

Second, replace div with span

`<div class="uniqstock"> 20</div>` to `<span class="uniqstock"> 20</span>`